# Extending FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

I am trying to extend the FloatingActionButton in my application. When I try to build I get a compiler error. If I remove the class that extends FloatingActionButton then my application will compile

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

The error seems to only happen when I add methods to the extend class.

This Compiles

```
public class TriedFAB extends FloatingActionButton {
    public TriedFAB(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TriedFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TriedFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
//    private void failCompile(){
//
//    }
}
```

This causes a compiler error

```
public class TriedFAB extends FloatingActionButton {
    public TriedFAB(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TriedFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TriedFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    private void failCompile(){

    }
}
```

Edit 3:

Looks like my application is too big and hit the dex limit

Comment: This error message doesn't tell us anything, you need to get the error message for `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION`

Comment: Please include your code. Also, what is your question?

Comment: This is the only error message i see where do i get the error from?

Answer (score 0):

try like this.Declare in xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myfloatingbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"

    />
```

Use like this then

```
 floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.myfloatingbutton);
    //handle FloatingActionButton Click
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FloatingActionButton is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

[Refer here for more](https://coderzpassion.com/android-material-design-floatingactionbutton/).

Comment: I am trying to extend the FloatingActionButton class

Comment: @user1634451 ok got it, will try and then i will be able to give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Hit the dex limit see it not in the messages but the gradle console

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: Try using MultiDexing library